# Robolectric does not support API level 27

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am using `3.3.2` Version of Roboelectric for Testing in my Android application. I am getting the following error when i ran my first test.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Robolectric does not support API level 27.
```

my SDK version is

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

Gradle Dependency is

```
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8"
```

And my test class starts like this

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 27)
public class TimeTableListPresenterTest {
```

Is roboelectirc is not supported with SDK version 27 ? Or i am missing something about that?

Comment: It is supported but you should use a recent version of Robolectric. Which is 3.8 now.

Comment: Changing the dependency to 3.8 resolve the issue and It run like a charm, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latest version which has fixed this issue.

```
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.1-SNAPSHOT"
```